# C++ Desktop application integration with Windows 10 Calendar App

Tags: c++, visual-c++, calendar, windows-10-desktop

Is it possible to integrate with Windows 10 Calendar App using C++?

I would like to add a new local Calendar and manage events on it, set attendance, etc..

Comment: Look at [Outlook calendar API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-calendar-concept-overview).

Comment: @S.M. I want to integrate with [native Calendar App](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mail-and-calendar-for-windows-10-faq-4ebe0864-260f-4d3a-a607-7b9899a98edc?wt.mc_id=win10_mailcal_settings_help_openhelp&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) not outlook calendar.

Comment: This is not a native calendar app, this is a UWP app, that is integrated with outlook.